# Is PATH or Java_Home messed up?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I was able to install Java and SonarQube, configured the wrapper.conf, and adjusted the port to 9000 to make it work 3 days ago.
Now, running StartSonar.bat gave this

> Unable to execute Java command.  Access is denied. (0x5) wrapper  |
> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin" -Dsonar.wrapped=true ...

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin` is what I have in wrapper.conf and it did work.

In a cmd window, `C:\windows\system32>java -version`

> java version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS-194, mixed mode)

navigate to the path above do `java -version` reports the same.

However I noticed my system Path has this, verified the one in `javapath` is the same version.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath 
C:\Program Files(x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

[image]

And java_home is empty: `echo %java_home%` got `%java_home%`

I'm totally confused now. What went wrong?

Comment: “…it did work.”  Not the way you have it now.  `jdk-11.0.11\bin` is not an executable program.  `jdk-11.0.11\bin\java.exe` is.

Comment: @VGR Sorry for the confusion. I meant after making the adjustment into `wrapper.conf` it was working. But good point, appended `\java` works. If you'd like to make an Answer, I'll Accept it. Thank you.